# token name 'app' is not defined. Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying implement a flask app with factory design pattern. Not able to run the app because of this error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2018 18:07:14] "OPTIONS /api/v1/users/register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
token name 'app' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2018 18:07:15] "POST /api/v1/users/register HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__ 
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app 
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function 
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception 
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise 
    raise value
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app 
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request 
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function 
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in 
    reraise raise value
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request 
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jacobo/.local/share/virtualenvs/alen-yVjuFfoa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request 
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Jacobo/Projects/alen/server/users/api.py", line 25, in register 
   'token': token.decode()
AttributeError: 'NameError' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

My project structure is as follows:

```
/ myapp
  /users
    api.py
    models.py
  app.py
  database.py
  extensions.py
  settings.py
run.py
```

I think that the problem is that app is not recognized app config. But I don't know how to make it work.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from server import users
from server.extensions import bcrypt, db, migrate, cors
from server.settings import DevConfig


def create_app(config_object=DevConfig):
    app = Flask(__name__,
                static_folder="../frontend/public",
                template_folder="../frontend/public")
    app.config.from_object(config_object)
    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    return app


def register_extensions(app):
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    cors.init_app(app)
    return None


def register_blueprints(app):
    app.register_blueprint(users.api.blueprint)
    return None
```

**settings.py**

```
import os


class Config(object):

    SECRET_KEY = 'p9Bv<3Eid9%$i01'
    APP_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))  # This directory
    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(APP_DIR, os.pardir))
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 13
    DEBUG_TB_ENABLED = False 
    DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = database


class ProdConfig(Config):
    ENV = 'prod'
    DEBUG = False
    DEBUG_TB_ENABLED = False  

class DevConfig(Config):
    ENV = 'dev'
    DEBUG = True
    DEBUG_TB_ENABLED = True
```

**/users/api.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request, make_response
from .models import User
from server.extensions import db
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

blueprint = Blueprint('user', __name__, url_prefix='/api/v1/users')


@blueprint.route("/register", methods=['POST'])
def register():
    data = request.get_json()
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=data.get('email')).first()
    if not user:
            user = User(
                email=data["email"],
                password=data["password"]
            )
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            token = user.encode_auth_token(user.id)
            print('token', token)
            responseObject = {
                'status': 'success',
                'message': 'Succesfully registered.',
                'token': token.decode()
            }
            return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 201

    else:
        responseObject = {
            'status': 'fail',
            'message': 'User already exists. Please log in.'
        }
        return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 202
```

**/users/models.py**

```
import datetime as dt
import jwt

from server.database import Column, Model, SurrogatePK
from server.database import db, reference_col, relationship
from server.extensions import bcrypt


class Role(SurrogatePK, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    name = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    user_id = reference_col('users', nullable=True)
    user = relationship('User', backref='roles')

    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self, name=name, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Represent instance as a unique string."""
        return '<Role({name})>'.format(name=self.name)


class User(SurrogatePK, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    email = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                        default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    active = Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    is_admin = Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)

    def __init__(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self, email=email, **kwargs)
        if password:
            self.set_password(password)
        else:
            self.password = None

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode()

    def check_password(self, value):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User({email!r})>'.format(email=self.email)

    def encode_auth_token(self, user_id):
        try:
            payload = {
                'exp': dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(days=0, seconds=5),
                'iat': dt.datetime.utcnow(),
                'sub': user_id
            }
            return jwt.encode(
                payload,
                app.config.get('SECRET_KEY'),
                algorithm='HS256'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return e

    @staticmethod
    def decode_auth_token(auth_token):
        """
        Validates the auth token
        :param auth_token:
        :return: integer|string
        """
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(auth_token, app.config.get('SECRET_KEY'))
            is_blacklisted_token = BlacklistToken.check_blacklist(auth_token)
            if is_blacklisted_token:
                return 'Token blacklisted. Please log in again.'
            else:
                return payload['sub']
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return 'Signature expired. Please log in again.'
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            return 'Invalid token. Please log in again.'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is pretty clear and has nothing to do with Flask itself.

```
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Jacobo/Projects/alen/server/users/api.py", line 25, in register 
   'token': token.decode()
AttributeError: 'NameError' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

The object `token` is not something that has `decode` (I'm assuming it should be `bytes`); it's instead a `NameError` object.

If we trace back to where `token` comes from, it comes from your `def encode_auth_token(self, user_id):` function – the problem there is that any exceptions are *returned* instead of being properly handled (or rather, not handled, so they'll raise an exception):

```
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

I'd suggest removing that exception handling altogether so you can get at the root cause (which could be e.g. `SECRET_KEY` having to be bytes, not a string, but you'll find that out).

Comment: I have removed try and except and now the error is: 
`File "/mnt/c/Users/Jacobo/Projects/alen/server/users/models.py", line 72, in encode_auth_token app.config.get('SECRET_KEY'), 
NameError: name 'app' is not defined`

 I don't understand why config is not loaded. This is my run.py file 

`from flask.helpers import get_debug_flag

from server.app import create_app
from server.settings import DevConfig, ProdConfig
CONFIG = DevConfig if get_debug_flag() else ProdConfig
app = create_app(CONFIG)`

Comment: You haven't imported `app` in that module.

Comment: ok, but if I add from server.app import app in models.py I have "cannot import app". circular dependencies?

Comment: Any help?? Thanks